# Estimate of AUC and mean growth time from a growth curve?

Tags: calculus, regression

Consider a four parameter hill function as follows to describe a growth curve.

$$
f(t) = y_0 + \frac{a \times t^b}{c^b + t^b}
$$

The area under the curve is estimated as follows.

$$
AUC = \int_{t=0}^{t_{max}}f(t)
$$

Which is described as

$$
AUC = \frac{\sum_{t=0}^{t_{max \times 10}} \left [ y_0 + \frac{a \times (t/10)^b}{c^b + (t/10)^b} \right ]}{10}
$$

How the above expression can be explained?

Also mean growth time (not rate) is described as

$$
MGT = \frac{\frac{\sum_{t=0}^{t_{max \times 1000}} \left [ \left ( y_0 + \frac{a \times (\frac{t}{1000})^b}{c^b + (\frac{t-1}{1000})^b} \right )-\left ( y_0 + \frac{a \times (\frac{t-1}{1000})^b}{c^b + (\frac{t-2}{1000})^b} \right ) \right ]}{1000}}{a}
$$

How to explain MGT in terms of calculus?